# Ionic 2 doesn’t generate scss source maps. “main.css.map” contains “null”

Tags: sass, webpack, ionic2, source-maps

Could you help me to understand why Ionic 2 doesn't generate scss source maps.
After "ionic serve" I'm navigating to www/build folder, there is main.css.map but it contains null instead of generated sourcemaps, how to fix it? Anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to extend your sass.config.js file, by default source mapping for sass is disabled.

config/sass.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  sourceMap: true,
}
```

package.json:

```
"config": {
  "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js",
},
```

https://github.com/GerritErpenstein/ionic2-custom-icons/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md

Cheers,

Comment: Hi. I had asked the same question on another post and this answer solves the problem. I have put your post as reference on the answer. Thanks
Here ismy [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818757/cannot-view-scss-files-while-working-with-ionic-on-dev-tools)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the CSS sourcemaps generated by this code won't actually map correctly. However, I found that adding `outputStyle: 'compressed',` to the package.json solves this problem.