# Cannot view scss files while working with Ionic on dev tools

Tags: ionic-framework, source-maps, developer-tools

I'm trying out some very basic Ionic tutorials from Ionic website ([Ionic Tutorial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/)), and i want to be able to view and modify scss from dev tools.

The app functions correctly, css classes i've added in scss files work correctly as well but i see a main.css file instead of the foo.css from which it was compiled. I can even view typescript files on dev tools and debug, which means source map for **js->ts is working**. It's **the css-> scss that's not working**.

I can see these files on www/build

- main.js
- main.map.js
- main.css
- main.map.css

Which means the source map is generated correctly. 
I have also enabled css source maps in chrome from
 - DevTools -> Settings ->Sources -> Enable CSS source maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would mark this as duplicate but it seems like i cannot. Answer can be found on this SO post[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534941/ionic-2-doesn-t-generate-scss-source-maps-main-css-map-contains-null). Basically,

You'll need to extend your sass.config.js file, by default source mapping for sass is disabled.

config/sass.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  sourceMap: true,
}
```

package.json:

```
"config": {
  "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js",
}
```

I can verify that this works.